# How do I get an image to display if a certain number of boxes are checked

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

This is my current code, and I can't figure out how to change the image depending on whether the number of boxes selected is greater than or less then 3.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Done it, hope thats enough

Comment: No. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

You could write a little function (see below) which is fired everytime a checkbox checked value changes.

```
let count = 0;
Document.QuerySelectorAll('[name="ckb"]').forEach(function (ckb)
   {
      if (ckb.checked)
         count ++;
   });
if(count >= 3)
      Document.QuerySelector('Image').classList.Remove('hidden');
else
      Document.QuerySelector('Image').classList.Add('hidden');
```

The hidden class should be added in your css and to the Image you want to hide.
It could look like this:

```
.hidden {
   opacity = 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that it solves his problem

Comment: edited it after his further explanation.